# python 3 regex string matching ignore whitespace and string.punctuation

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, pattern-matching, non-alphanumeric

I am new to regex and would like to know how to pattern match two strings. The use case would be something like finding a certain phrase in some text. I'm using python 3.7 if that makes a difference.

```
phrase = "some phrase" #the phrase I'm searching for
```

Possible matches:

```
text = "some#@$#phrase"
            ^^^^ #non-alphanumeric can be treated like a single space
text = "some   phrase"
text = "!!!some!!! phrase!!!"
```

These are not matches:

```
text = "some phrases"
                   ^ #the 's' on the end makes it false
text = "ssome phrase"
text = "some other phrase"
```

I have tried using something like:

```
re.search(r'\b'+phrase+'\b', text)
```

I would very much appreciate an explanation of why the regex works if you provide a valid solution.

Comment: Please edit your question because its not clear what do you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
re.search(r'\bsome\W+phrase\b', text)
```

- '\W' means non-word character
- '+' means one or more times

In case you have a given phrase in a variable, you could try this before:

```
some_phrase = some_phrase.replace(r' ', r'\W+')
```

Comment: some_phrase = some_phrase.replace(r' ', r'\W+') prints 'some\W+phrase'.

Comment: finally you put \b at the begining and the end.

Comment: does not this solve your problem? please explain to me on what you are stuck

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Perform the replace and then search using that string. Yes that is what I needed. Thank you.